# Multiple tablix for report

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools, ssrs-tablix

i have the following scenario i am trying to simplify using Visual Studio and Microsoft BI Stack (SSRS).

I have a Dataset as follows.

```
Year    Employee    Sales
1       A           5,000,000
2       A           7,500,000
3       A           6,500,000
1       B           3,500,000
2       B           5,000,000
3       B           8,000,000
1       C           5,750,000
2       C           7,500,000
3       C           6,500,000
1       D           4,500,000
2       D           5,500,000
3       D           6,100,000
```

I am trying to create a report whereby, a single report would span 3 Tablix inside report body when run to display as follows.

**Year 1**

```
Year    Employee    Sales
1       A           5,000,000
1       B           3,500,000
1       C           5,750,000
1       D           4,500,000
```

**Year 2**

```
Year    Employee    Sales
2       A           7,500,000
2       B           5,000,000
2       C           7,500,000
2       D           5,500,000
```

**Year 3**

```
Year    Employee    Sales
3       A           6,500,000
3       B           8,000,000
3       C           6,500,000
3       D           6,100,000
```

Now i know i could replicate the Tablix 3 times in the report body, but that would be a bad idea when it comes to maintaining this report.

In the effort to avoid repeating myself, is there a way to loop the Tablix (N Times) in SSRS where condition would be the **Year** column (values 1, 2, 3.....)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the steps :-

1. Insert a List. Group it by the Year.
2. Put your tablix inside the list.

This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to NEST two tables.

First, create your table that gives you all the results like you want.

Then create a second table with one column and one row and Group it by your **Year** field.

Place your first table in the second table's so that it repeats for each year.